# Nested Join query enum values show up as integers in its json representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

When doing a select of a nested association enum value and changing it to its json representation these values wont convert to strings, any other simple join value has its string representation.

Enum: (Example, real enum has more values)

```
enum category_type: [:gender, :another_value]
```

Query: (Example, real query has more joins and fields)

```
  def self.report
    select_fields = 'question_categories.category_type'

    joins(question: :question_category)
      .select(select_fields)
      .group('question_categories.category_type')
  end
```

JSON: Right Now

```
[{"id"=>nil, "category_type"=>0},
 {"id"=>nil, "category_type"=>1}]
```

JSON: What i want to see

```
[{"id"=>nil, "category_type"=>"gender"},
 {"id"=>nil, "category_type"=>"another value"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: So... you want something that converts the actual representation of the enum (which is 0-8) converted to a string-representation of the rails-visible enum value (eg "gender")... ?

Comment: Hi @TarynEast Yes I want to see the string representation in json (I updated my question with examples), any other value required in the query (not shown in this example) has its string representation but I don't know what is going on when doing a nested join

Comment: When you use as_json enum values are shown in strings and it is not working in this example.